# ElasticSearch : limit results for a field value

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm working on a search service using ElasticSearch. I try to limit my results number by field value. For example, I had "comments" with field "user" (without parent/child for this example) and I want to search "comments" limit to 2 by user.

I tried something with aggregations and toHits which give me good results.

```
"aggs": {
  "agg": {
    "terms": {"field": "user","size":10},
    "aggs": {
      "topHits": { "top_hits": {"size": 2}}
   }
 }
```

And I get results like that :

```
"aggregations": {
"agg": {
  "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
  "sum_other_doc_count": 5,
  "buckets": [
    {
      "key": "user1",
      "doc_count": 5,
      "topHits": {
        "hits": {
          "total": 5,
          "hits": [
            {
              "_index": "idx",
              "_type": "comments",
              "_id": "comment1",
              "_source": {
                "user": "user1",
                "headline": "Bla bla 1"
              }
            },{
              "_index": "idx",
              "_type": "comments",
              "_id": "comment2",
              "_source": {
                "user": "user1",
                "headline": "Bla bla 2"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },{
      "key": "user2",
      "doc_count": 1,
      "topHits": {
        "hits": {
          "total": 1,
          "hits": [
            {
              "_index": "idx",
              "_type": "comments",
              "_id": "comment3",
              "_source": {
                "user": "user2",
                "headline": "Bla bla 3"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
```

But if i do that, I can't manage target "fields" and the total count is the number of users (not the number of comment).

Do you know a solution (maybe by post_filter ? script ?) to build filter directly in the query ?